# Resizing a selected area in a PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu, pdf

I am looking for a program that can resize a selected area in a PDF.

E.g. on Microsoft Windows with Microsoft Paint I can use the "Resize" feature:

[image]

(but Microsoft Paint doesn't support PDF and is not vectorial).

I would prefer if the program works with Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

---

Attempts:

- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) can resize a selected area in a PDF but it loses the page structure.
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a [raster graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) editor application (i.e. not vectorial).

Comment: I wish there was an app which combined certain PDF support features of both Inkscape (ability to modify vector graphics) and Gimp (imported PDF actually looks like the original).

Comment: @MarcinKaminski Yes I agree that could be the ideal!

Answer (score 1):

Gimp which is available in most Linux distributions can do that easily.

```
sudo aptitude install gimp
```

Then open a PDF in it, select an area, Tools > Transform tools > Scale. When you're done, export as a PDF.

UPDATE: If you care about importing PDFs ehile preserving their vector structure, you can use Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks, but upon importing a PDF into GIMP the image is not vectorial anymore :(

Comment: Ah, updated my answer. It's been a while since I've seen a PDF that isn't a crappy bitmap. Let me know if that works for you. I'd be also happy for others come up with other recommendations. BTW: PDFEdit - don't touch this with a stick...

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used Inkscape indeed as my PDF was just one page but if you you are aware of a solution that works for multipage PDF I would be interested!

Comment: I usually don't mind editing multiple pages separately. I have a bunch of shell functions (ImageMagick wrappers) that I use for splitting, merging and extracting pages from PDFs, so that's not a deal breaker for me. I can share those if you wish.